# RFID can't read tag ID and data at the same time

Tags: arduino, rfid

Win-10, Arduino IDE 1.8.13, Arduino NANO, MFRC522 Library.
All code based on the provided library samples.

GOAL: I want to read the card ID + read + write to a card without having to remove and re-enter the antenna field.

I wrote separate sketches for each operation and each works independently. When I combined the code into one sketch it will read the card ID but fails to do the read/write functions. If I comment out all but one call I can ReadCardData() or WriteCardData() or CardId(). I know it has to do with how the card is detected/halted but I can't figure out the right combination. Any suggestions on what to do?

QUESTION: Is there a way I can read the card ID (sector 0 block 0) and extract the value without having to use the IsNewCardPresent()?

Some unrelated code has been cropped .......
data results placed in declared variables.

loop from combined functions

```
     void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(DropOff)== LOW){
    digitalWrite(Red, HIGH);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(Red, LOW);
  }
  if(digitalRead(PickUp)== LOW){
    digitalWrite(Green, HIGH);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(Green, LOW);
  }
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
  delay(1000);
  cardTime = millis();
  A = cardTime - holdTime;
  if (A >= 2000){
    Serial.print("A = ");
    Serial.println(A);
     // WriteCardData();
     // delay(3000);
     //CardId();
      ReadCardData ();
      // WriteCardData();
      holdTime = cardTime;
  } else {
    //holdTime = cardTime;
  }
```

all these function work

```
void CardId(){

if (  mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()){
    //Serial.println(F("A new card is Present"));
  mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial();
  tagString = "";
  tagString = String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0]);
  tagString = tagString + String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1]);
  tagString = tagString + String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2]);
  tagString = tagString + String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3]);
  Serial.print("UID = ");
  Serial.println(tagString);
  //closeCard();
  delay(200);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(tagString);
} // end main if
else {
  closeCard();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("no card");
}
} // end function

// **************************************************************
void ReadCardData (){
    String myTest = "";
    myTest = openCard();
    Serial.println(myTest);
    carType = ReadBlock(1,4,7);
    Serial.print("carType = ");
    Serial.println(carType);
    carColor = ReadBlock(1,5,7);
    Serial.print("carColor = ");
    Serial.println(carColor);
    carName = ReadBlock(1,6,7);
    Serial.print("carName = ");
    Serial.println(carName);
    carNumber = ReadBlock(2,8,11);
    Serial.print("carNumber = ");
    Serial.println(carNumber);
    carOwner = ReadBlock(2,9,11);
    Serial.print("carOwner = ");
    Serial.println(carOwner);
    closeCard();
}

// *************************************************************
void WriteCardData (){
    openCard();
    isGood = WriteBlock(carType,4,7);
    //Serial.print("carType = ");
    Serial.println(isGood);
    isGood = WriteBlock(carColor,5,7);
    //Serial.print("carColor = ");
    Serial.println(isGood);
    isGood = WriteBlock(carName,6,7);
    //Serial.print("carName = ");
    Serial.println(isGood);
    isGood = WriteBlock(carNumber,8,11);
    //Serial.print("carNumber = ");
    Serial.println(isGood);
    isGood = WriteBlock(carOwner,9,11);
    //Serial.print("carOwner = ");
    Serial.println(isGood);
    closeCard();
}




// ***************************************************************************
void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        //Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
        //Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
        msgArray[i] = buffer[i];
       //Serial.print(msgArray[i]);
    }

}

// **********************************************************************
String openCard(){
 /* int z = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
         if ( mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()){
            break;
         }else{ 
              z = ++z; 
              if (z = 4){
                 return "loop failed";
              }   
         }
    }
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()){
        return "read failed";
    }
    */
    while ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
     //do nothing
  }
  mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent();
return "got it!";
}
// ********************************************************************
void closeCard(){
     // Halt PICC
    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
    // Stop encryption on PCD
    mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();
}
// *********************************************************************
String ReadBlock (int sector, int blockAddr, int trailerBlock){
 
    //MFRC522::StatusCode status;
    byte buffer[18];
    byte size = sizeof(buffer);
    // Authenticate using key A
    //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
    status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, trailerBlock, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
         //Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
         //Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return "failed";
    }
    // Read data from the block
     //Serial.print(F("Reading data from block ")); Serial.print(blockAddr);
     //Serial.println(F(" ..."));
    status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(blockAddr, buffer, &size);
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        // Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Read() failed: "));
        // Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return "failed";
    }
    //Serial.print(F("Data in block ")); Serial.print(blockAddr); Serial.println(F(":"));
    dump_byte_array(buffer, 16); Serial.println();

    Serial.println();
    String q = "";
    int t = 0;
    int w = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++){
      t = msgArray[i] + 0;
      if (t<32 || t>126)        // check for random byte values that aren't acceptable ASCII
        {
           msgArray[i] = 32;    // change bad value to a space bar
        }
    }    
    q = msgArray;    
    q.trim();                   // get rid of trailing spaces
    w = q.length();
     //Serial.print("size of array = ");
     //Serial.println(w);
     //Serial.println(q);
    if (w < 1){                 // test for empty string -- will pass random printable ASCII
      return "unknown";
    }else{

      return q;
    }
}
// ********************************************
String WriteBlock (String storeData, int blockAddr, int trailerBlock){
    // Serial.println("enter function");
    storeData.trim();
    int w = storeData.length();
    if (w < 16) {
      for (int i=0; i < (16-w); i++){
        storeData += " ";
      }
      // Serial.println("pad data");
      for (int i=0; i < 16; i++){
        myBlock[i] = storeData[i];
      }
    }
    else if (w > 16){
       for (int i=0; i < 16; i++){
        myBlock[i] = storeData[i];
      }
      // Serial.println("remove data");
    }
    //MFRC522::StatusCode status;
    byte buffer[18];
    byte size = sizeof(buffer);
    // Authenticate using key A
    // Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
    status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, trailerBlock, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        //Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
        //Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return "failed";
    }
 
    // Write data to the block
    // Serial.print(F("Writing data into block ")); Serial.print(blockAddr);
    // Serial.println(F(" ..."));
    //dump_byte_array(myBlock, 16); Serial.println();
    status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(blockAddr, myBlock, 16);
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        // Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
        // Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
         return "failed";
    }
    // Serial.println("end of function");
return "good";





}
// ********************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Nano had near full memory and unstable. Removed all openCard() & closecard() and placed in the main "loop" of the program only. Set flag if card had been opened. Called readCard() or writeCard() as needed. Had read/write set flag to trigger closeCard() at the bottom of main loop.